# Inserting RTL text in verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim, right-to-left, xepersian, persian

How I can insert Persian text in verbatim environment when using XePersin package
( v11.138, 2012/05/03). Following code dose not work:

```
\begin{verbatim}

<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
"http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<book>
  <bookinfo>
    <title> عنوان کتاب </title>
    <author>
    </author>
  </bookinfo>
 محتوای کتاب
</book>

\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: The `verbatim` environment uses only one font, so you need a monospaced font that contains Latin and Persian glyphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code by [Vafa Khalighi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19785/vafa):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{myverbatim}{Verbatim}{commandchars=+\[\]}
\begin{document}
%\begin{latin}
\begin{myverbatim}

<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
"http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<book>
  <bookinfo>
    <title> +rl[عنوان کتاب] </title>
    <author>
    </author>
  </bookinfo>
+rl[ محتوای کتاب]
</book>

              +rl[دکتر] 

\end{myverbatim}
%\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Reza: Additionally, for more examples and information, you are very welcome to visit the [ParsiLatex](http://www.parsilatex.com/) website.

Comment: Thanks. This do not work as expected. Even wore than egreg's answer

Comment: @Reza: See my update. For more information, you can see [this](http://www.parsilatex.com/forum/SMF/index.php?topic=3494.0) topic.

Comment: @Reza: Yes, it is. By the way, if everything is OK with my code above, you should accept it as your answer, according to the site's rule.

Comment: Is [ ] wrappers really needed, in your linked page Khalighi presented a not working code that dose not have any wrapper inside verbatim environment, can you also fix that solution too?

Comment: Hello and excuse me for commenting all this time ago. Wgat happens with the [ ] wrappers. We need to put it in verbatim environments for options of packages !

Answer (score 6):

The `verbatim` environment uses only one font, so you need a monospaced font that contains both Latin and Persian glyphs. Here's an example (but I don't know Persian, so it might be not perfect):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}

<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
"http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<book>
  <bookinfo>
    <title> عنوان کتاب </title>
    <author>
    </author>
  </bookinfo>
 محتوای کتاب
</book>

\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Persian is a RTL languages. The issue is 'عنوان کتاب' in text is rendered as 'کتاب عنوان' in PDF, usually Persian files use XePersian package in general, but even when I use it  verbatim environment have the issue yet, Perhaps there is a config that I forget to set.

Comment: @Reza I'm afraid that this is an inherent limitation of the `verbatim` environment, where it's quite difficult, as it is now, to change the writing direction. :(