# verbatim with Arabic script

Tags: verbatim, arabic, bidi, persian

I try to put together guidelines for linguists. One part concernes typesetting right to left text with the `bidi` package. I want to use `verbatim` for the code, but the Persian characters are not printed correctly in the `verbatim` environment. But the following code does not work. I also had a look at a solution for [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73464/inserting-rtl-text-in-verbatim-environment?rq=1), but this did not work either.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}

\begin{document}

\PRL{او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.}

\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage{fontspec}\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}

\PRL{او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.}
\end{verbatim}


\end{document}
```

This was the second attempt according to the other suggested solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\usepackage{bidi}
\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}


\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{rtlverbatim}{Verbatim}{commandchars=+\[\]}

\begin{document}

\PRL{او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.}

\begin{latin}
\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage{fontspec}\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}

\PRL{او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.}
\end{verbatim}
\end{latin}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not understand the concept of the solution correctly

1. You should use the new defined verbatim environment `rtlverbatim`;
2. Persian text should be surrounded by `+PRL[...]` to be displayed correctly in verbatim environment.

You may also like to define a separate Persian font for you verbatim Persian text. See `XePersian` documentation to see the effect.

Your example should be modified like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}


\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{rtlverbatim}{Verbatim}{commandchars=+\[\]}

\begin{document}

\PRL{او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.}

\begin{latin}
\begin{rtlverbatim}
\usepackage{fontspec}\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}

\PRL{+PRL[او مرد را دوست نخواهد داشت.]}
\end{rtlverbatim}
\end{latin}


\end{document}
```