# Hebrew within sourcecode

Tags: verbatim, sourcecode, hebrew, right-to-left

I need to include LaTeX source code, which contains Hebrew text, within an Hebrew document.
I tried doing so within a *verbatim* environment, but Hebrew words appear in opposite order. Any solution without use *verbatim* would also be satisfactory.

Tried the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73464/inserting-rtl-text-in-verbatim-environment) with and without *xepersian*, and both failed. The first one failed due to the font missing, the latter because *rl* wasn't recognised.

Source code:

```
 \begin{english}
 \begin{verbatim}
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian]{hebrew} 
 \setotherlanguage{english}

 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}%Liberation Serif
 \setromanfont{Times New Roman}
 \setmonofont{Times New Roman}
 \setmainfont[Script=Hebrew, AutoFakeSlant=-0.15]{Times New Roman}
 % Fix section numbering bug of Polyglossia
 \renewcommand\SepMark[1]{\def\@SepMark{#1}}\SepMark{.}

 \title{מסמך לדוגמה}
 \author{יונתן סמית}

 \begin{document}
 \maketitle
 שלום עולם! 
 \end{document}
 \end{verbatim}
 \end{english}
```

Result:

[image: PDF result]

Comment: How about the `babel` and `lualatex` solution in this answer? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390345/87678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you have suggested works. The definition is of a new verbatim environment in which anything after the `+` is used as a latex command. In the answer, you brought `+rl[somethingsomething]` is identified in verbatim, and translated into `\rl{somethingsomething}` LaTeX command.

All you need to do is use the right command, not `rl`, rather `\texthebrew`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Language=Hebrew,Script=Hebrew]{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}{DejaVu Sans}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{myverbatim}{Verbatim}{commandchars=+\[\]}


\begin{document}
 \begin{english}
 \begin{myverbatim}
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian]{hebrew} 
 \setotherlanguage{english}

 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}%Liberation Serif
 \setromanfont{Times New Roman}
 \setmonofont{Times New Roman}
 \setmainfont[Script=Hebrew, AutoFakeSlant=-0.15]{Times New Roman}
 % Fix section numbering bug of Polyglossia
 \renewcommand\SepMark[1]{\def\@SepMark{#1}}\SepMark{.}

 \title{+texthebrew[מסמך לדוגמה]}
 \author{+texthebrew[יונתן סמית]}

 \begin{document}
 \maketitle
+texthebrew[ שלום עולם! ]
 \end{document}
 \end{myverbatim}
 \end{english}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Result]
notice two things:

1. DejaVu Sans is used - this is a font with Hebrew support, you can use any other.
2. You also need to define a `hebrewfonttt` family, or otherwise you'll get an error that the roman font does not contain the Hebrew script