# verbatim + hebrew + xelatex

Tags: xetex, verbatim, right-to-left

I need to typeset Hebrew text, using xelatex, in a monospace font and a `verbatim` context. All the paragraphs should be RTL. How can I specify, using `\fontspec`, the font for `verbatim` mode?

Comment: As already said in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73464/inserting-rtl-text-in-verbatim-environment#comment183266_85139) comment, RTL seems to be a problem. Otherwise it's pretty simple to use a Hebrew font with `fontspec`.

Comment: I know how to use a Hebrew/Arabic font. The problem is indeed the verbatim. But the original verbatim mode has been rewritten numerous times. Surely there must be some workaround!